# How do i set a default image when the user doesn`t upload any image?

Tags: php, image

How can I set a default image to `upload/'default image.jpg'` to use it when user doesn't upload his own image?

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);          
$location = "upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

Comment: Just start by checking if any file actually exist in the `$_FILES['image']`. If it doesn't, skip the rest of this script and set `$location` to the default instead

Comment: i tried change 
     $location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
into
     $location="upload/default.jpg" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

but when i upload a photo it doesnt show the image i uploaded

Comment: If there's no image uploaded, _don't_ use `$_FILES` at all. That is _just for the uploaded file_.

Comment: Some explanations when does he need default image

Comment: Well, it seems like the OP gave up...

Answer (score 1):

You should start by checking if there even was a file uploaded before you're trying to use it.

```
// Here's the default value
$location = "upload/default_image.jpg";

// Check if we got an uploaded file
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    // We have an uploaded file, now let's handle it
    $image      = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]) {
        // Yay! It worked! Let's overwrite our default value!
        $location = "upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    }
}

// The rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, start with a default file name in the `$location` variable, and overwrite it if needed

```
$location = "upload/default image.jpg"; // the default file value
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]) 
{          
    // only change the location if something was uploaded
    $location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
}
```